# Best image matching algorithm for accuracy?

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

So I'm working on some code to determine what denomination of East Caribbean Dollar based on a 4 bpp grayscale image. I'm already taking care of any skewing/distortions but I'm looking for an image matching algorithm. I was thinking of using FFT but does anyone have any other suggestions for an algorithm that has a higher accuracy? Speed is not critical. I've added a sample image.

[Sample specimen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHyzp.png)

Comment: Show your processed image after "taking care of any skewing/distortions"

Comment: Bit off-topic here. Anyway, what would you expect to achieve with a FFT? Focus on edge detection, especially for digit recognition.

Comment: It's not really about digit recognition per se. Edge detection and skew is already being handled, but I've had some issues with template matching in the past which is why I was hoping for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shoud have some template denominations. 
Let us say you have those at same scale.
Then you may try [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=cvmatch#void%20cvMatchTemplate%28const%20CvArr%2a%20image,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20templ,%20CvArr%2a%20result,%20int%20method%29) using Normalized Cross Correlation (NCC) to find out how each of those denomination is matching with yourcurrent doller image.
Even though NCC seems simple, it can do wonders in reality.
the one which gives best matching score is the denomination.
You may try with both templates you have on your speciman image to be more robust.
It does not matter if it is 4 bpp or 8bpp.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Also, one follow up question. Any suggestions on determining the best template locations for more robust results and faster processing? Also any weaknesses that I should be aware of?

Comment: You can improve the robustness by preprocessing the image to remove any distortion/scale. You may want to improve the robustness by double checking the letters (FIVE in your specimen) ( at second stage for faster processing). The templates must be unique to others and in local neighborhood.